# Plotting function on sphere (color and shape)

Tags: matlab, function, plot, geometry

**EDIT**

A function f(x,y,z) is defined on the unit sphere (x,y,z) in S2. I have to plot it on the unit sphere not just by color.

I have tried surf(x,y,z,f) but it just colores the sphere with respect to the values of f. But I need to transform the unit sphere into an "egg". Namely, if at some point the value of function f=2, for example - I have to stretch the sphere at this point in the direction of unit normal twice the original value of z. And the same for all points and values of f.

```
for i=1:N
     for ii=1:N1+1
         [x(i,ii) y(i,ii) z(i,ii)]=sph2cart(phi(ii),acos(cosTeta(i))+pi/2,RO);

         Y_exact(i,ii)=FrankeF(x(i,ii), y(i,ii), z(i,ii));
         cap_point=-0.5*x(i,ii)-0.5*y(i,ii)+1/sqrt(2)*z(i,ii);

         if cap_point>=cos(0.5)
             f_cap(i,ii)=2*cos(pi*acos(cap_point));
         end

     end
end

Y_exact=Y_exact+f_cap;

surf(x,y,z,Y_exact,'FaceColor','interp','EdgeColor','none','FaceLighting','phong');
shading interp
axis square
colorbar
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And serously nobody is going to download a paper to get the information to answer a simple plotting question. Improve your question and we'll help you ;)

Comment: Modified my question, sorry

Comment: But you're data actually represents an egg? So I assume you just have to set the [axis properties](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) to `axis normal` to get the right visual output.

Comment: I think this just change the point of view. What I need - I have to deform the original unit sphere according to new values of f (colormap defines the values of such deformation in each point in the direction of unit normal)

Comment: ... post some code...

Comment: you're never updating you actual z-data. I guess you rather use `surf(x,y,Y_exact,Y_exact,...` instead of the initial z-data. And as said before with `axis square` you visually never get an egg.

Comment: The resulting surface from your comment is just a "mountain", which has to be stretched on the sphere. This is the problem I am dealing with.

Comment: Colored sphere is very close to what I need. But I need to reshape my sphere according to the color also. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to post a picture with the goal =(. That is why I tried to add a link to the article...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for i=1:N
     for ii=1:N1+1       
[x1(i,ii) y1(i,ii) z1(i,ii)]=sph2cart(phi(ii),acos(cosTeta(i))+pi/2,RO+Y_exact(i,ii));
     end
  end

 figure(1);
 surf(x1,y1,z1,Y_exact,'FaceColor','interp','EdgeColor','none','FaceLighting','phong');
 shading interp
 axis normal
 colorbar
```

This is what I wanted.
[image]

Comment: I think you should make an example, assign values to N, N1, phi, cosTeta, RO and Y_exact - otherwise it's not simple to understand exactly what it is that you are doing …

Comment: Added some text description

Comment: And a picture also :)

Answer (score 0):

phi and teta - just my rectangular grid of nodes in spherical coordinates on the unit sphere (RO=1).
N and N1 their amount (NxN1 - the total amount of nodes)
Y_exact - my function on the sphere (Franke function) (NxN1 values)

First I calculate my grid in Cartesian coordinates and calculate the values of Y_exact. Then in each point on the sphere I stretch the sphere like RO+Y_exact and calculate corresponding new values of x and y in Cartesian coordinates.

As a result I receive the function Y_exact stretched on the unit sphere!

I will support this solution with picture when I get enough reputation

Comment: It would be better if you posted all the code. BTW, perhaps you can avoid the double loop?

Comment: My code is somehow specific due to position of nodes. I think it will confuse the reader. One may use classical sphere(n) and get points immediately. I am dealing with different problem in my program - this is just the correct visualization of my research.